# Twigg eval analog

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Hi I have a question I have layout which is a file and internal template stored in database. I need to render whole page using twig. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how twig's [string loader](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Loader/String.php) works.

On the long term you're probably better off [creating your own loader](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#create-your-own-loader).